# Can't rotate player object properly while they are a child of another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I stand on an object that my player is parented to, rather than me being able to rotate my character object (capsule with an in-built controller) manually via my own horizontal mouse movement which is what I want, my player rotates WITH the parent object as if they are one. That makes sense because I have them parented, but I tried to counter it with a trigger so that my character will not rotate at all unless I manually turn around.

I thought this code below would work but it changes nothing, however debugging shows that the trigger itself + transform.isChildOf works (excluding the rotation code at the bottom).

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.transform.IsChildOf(transform))
        {
            return;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
    }
```

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter` will only be executed once when the object enters the trigger. Maybe you want [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)?

Comment: Are you sure you need this parent - child relationsship then? Usually you would want exactly that behavior given such a relationship. If you can make the player independent, do that. Alternatively, you could also establish a sibling relationship instead (player and current parent both children of a common parent). Then you still have somekind of relation if you need it but the transforms don't depend:)

Comment: The problem is you are trying to modify global rotation `transform.rotation` in place of `transform.localRotation`. When you do this under parent child relation Unity tries to set it repect to parent.